# jquery change more than one input type at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, woocommerce

i have created some other threads but without any working answers so far.

I have this code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$('.nm-myaccount-login-inner .form-row .lawrence_password span.required').append(
"<div class='hide-show'><span toggle='#password' class='fa fa-fw field-icon toggle-password fa-eye'></span></div>");

$('.nm-myaccount-login-inner .form-row .lawrence_register_password span.required').append(
"<div class='hide-show'><span toggle='#password' class='fa fa-fw field-icon toggle-password fa-eye'></span></div>");
});

jQuery(function($){
  $(".toggle-password").click(function() {

  $(this).toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash");
  var input = $($(this).attr("toggle"));
  if (input.attr("type") == "password") {
    input.attr("type", "text");
  } else {
    input.attr("type", "password");
  }
});


});
```

What this does is add an clickable icon to ".lawrence_password span" and "lawrence_register_password span".
Then when a person clicks the icon the input password will change its type from: `<input type="password">` to `<input type="text">` so the password becomes visible.

However this only affect my first input field, and not all my `<input type="password">`

I want this jquery function to apply to all `<input type="password">`

My html:

```
<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="password" class="lawrence_password">Password <span class="required">*<div class="hide-show"><span toggle="#password" class="fa fa-fw field-icon toggle-password fa-eye-slash"></span></div></span></label>
                    <input class="input-text" type="text" name="password" id="password">
                </p>
```

The register password input is indentical to this, it just have the class "lawrence_password_register".

Is this possible? Thank you!

Comment: Can you include your html? Please put it on Snippet

Comment: Hi i edited the post to include html :)

Comment: Your `input` variable is targeting an `id` and they should be unique, so it'll return just one element.

Comment: This HTML Shows 1 Input, what I wanted to check is the id's for each input as you seem to have more and that was to check because of the reason as explained by @msg

Comment: Do you want the button to reveal just it's corresponding `input` or every password field at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need to do is to use `class` instead of `id`. if you change `toggle="someClass"` attribute of `<span>` within `<div>` where each `<input type="password"/>` has class `class="someClass"`.

Below is an example where I set `class="password"` on inputs and then on your `<span toggle=".password">`... and that's all you need to change.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
  $('.lawrence_password span.required').append(
  "<div class='hide-show'><span toggle='.password' class='fa fa-fw field-icon toggle-password fa-eye'>Toggle Button</span></div>");

  $('.lawrence_register_password span.required').append(
  "<div class='hide-show'><span toggle='.password' class='fa fa-fw field-icon toggle-password fa-eye'>Toggle Button</span></div>");

  $(".toggle-password").click(function() {
    var input = $($(this).attr("toggle"));

    if (input.attr("type") === "password") {
      input.attr("type", "text");
    } else {
      input.attr("type", "password");
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="password" class="lawrence_password">Password <span class="required">*     </span></label>
    <input class="input-text password" type="password" name="password" id="password">
</p>
<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="password" class="lawrence_register_password">Password Register<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input class="input-text password" type="password" name="password" id="password">
</p>
```

Comment: Since he wants to change both.. why target them individually? Just use a class. That will allow you to simplify the first function as well.

Comment: Ok I missed that. Let me change my answer quickly. Thanks for the reminder @msg

Comment: I may be misinterpreting "I want this jquery function to apply to all password fields", though

Comment: He basically wants to use one code base even if he adds more `<input type="password" />`

Comment: Ill test it when i get home! Thank you :)

Comment: Would you mind if I edited your answer ? I have an improvement for the creation of the buttons, but looks like I didn't explain myself in the first comment.